# Assistance with Autolayout in Xcode 7

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, autolayout

I am really struggling with Auto layout in Xcode. I have a view with 5 buttons and 5 labels describing the buttons. The picture is below.

[image: Picture of view]

I am trying to use autolayout and adding all these constriants, but nothing is working for me. Can someone please explain what contraints to add for one of these buttons and the associated label in detail, and I will understand the rest.

Comment: What is the desired end result and what's wrong with it now?

Comment: I need it so the size of the buttons and labels keep the same position of screen and increase or decrease their size based on the size of the screen

Comment: What constraints have you added and what is happening when the screen size changes?

Comment: to temperature button I added a constraint for trailing space to container, top space to the container, and horizontal space to the humidity button. But when I run the app on larger screens then iphone 5, the spacing between the temperature button and trailing space to container increases

Comment: probably a conflicting constraint on the humidity button without seeing the list of all constraints

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of the resulting UI?